# Find point such that the triangle it makes with two distinct line segments are similar

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I was working on a proof about dilative rotations and, while I managed to prove a solution, I couldn't prove its uniqueness. Then I had the idea of proving that there was only one point such that those two mentioned triangles are similar. So given two pairs of points, how do I find a point C such that the this is the case? I tried using a bit of vector algebra and came up with the set of equations:

$\frac{\left\lVert C-B \right\rVert}{sin(\alpha)} = \frac{\left\lVert C-A \right\rVert}{sin(\beta)} = \frac{\left\lVert B-A \right\rVert}{sin(\theta)}$

$\frac{\left\lVert C-B' \right\rVert}{sin(\alpha)} = \frac{\left\lVert C-A' \right\rVert}{sin(\beta)} = \frac{\left\lVert B'-A' \right\rVert}{sin(\theta)}$

, where B-A is a one line segment(or vector), B'-A' is the other one and $\frac{\left\lVert C-B' \right\rVert}{\left\lVert C-B \right\rVert} = \frac{\left\lVert C-A' \right\rVert}{\left\lVert C-A \right\rVert} = \frac{\left\lVert A'-B' \right\rVert}{\left\lVert A-B \right\rVert} = r$

Problem is, this seems to get algebraically complicated really fast. Do you have any smarter ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point you are looking for of called the center of the [spiral similarity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_similarity). To prove uniqueness, observe that if $X'$ is another center, then $ABPX'$ and $DCPX'$ are also cyclic (I'm following the Wikipedia notation), since two distinct circles have at most two intersection points, and $X\neq P\neq X'$, we get that $X=X'$, which is what we wanted.

The proof may have several cases depending whether the lines $AC$ and $BD$ intersect inside the segments of not, but are all similar (you can avoid card using directed angles if you know then, but that's not necessary).